# jQuery fadeIn function doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a box, and when someon clicks `Tell Me More` the box with info has to slide in, but my jQuery doesn't do anything...

My jQuery:

```
<script>
$( "#vertel-me-meer" ).click(function() {
  $( "#weten" ).fadeIn( 'slow', function() {
  });
});
</script>
```

I've included the jQuery at the top of my page but I don't think it's neccesairy to put in in the code here. This is my CSS:

```
.meer {

font-size: 14px;
font-family: 'Ubuntu';
font-weight: bold;

color: #00748c;

}
#vertel-me-meer {
text-decoration: none;
position:absolute;
top:220px;
left:329px;
font-size:15px;
font-family: 'Ubuntu';
font-weight:bold;
font-style:italic;
color:#fff;
margin:40px 50px 0 0;
text-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

#weten{
display: none;
 position: relative;
bottom: 125px;
top: 250px;
left: 50px;
width:395px;
height:115px;
background:#c7dbe3;
background:rgba(199,219,227,0.90);
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
border-radius:5px;
border:1px solid #004f68;
box-shadow:3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
overflow:hidden
}
```

Ofcoure, my HTML:

```
<div id="vertel-me-meer"><p><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">Ik wil meer weten…</a></p></div>
<div id="weten" class="meer"><br>INFO</div>
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Where is the element `weten`?

Comment: Works as expected. http://jsfiddle.net/Yu2zB/

Answer (score 0):

Call it when DOM gets ready.

Make sure you have element `#weten` in your HTML.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#vertel-me-meer" ).click(function() {
        $( "#weten" ).fadeIn( 'slow', function() {
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

update your code by below written code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#weten" ).fadeIn( 'slow');
});
});
</script>
I've included the jQuery at the top of my page but I don't think it's neccesairy to put in in the code here. This is my CSS:
<style>
.meer {

font-size: 14px;
font-family: 'Ubuntu';
font-weight: bold;

color: #00748c;

}
#vertel-me-meer {
text-decoration: none;
position:absolute;
top:220px;
left:329px;
font-size:15px;
font-family: 'Ubuntu';
font-weight:bold;
font-style:italic;
color:#fff;
margin:40px 50px 0 0;
text-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

#weten{
display: none;
 position: relative;
bottom: 125px;
top: 250px;
left: 50px;
width:395px;
height:115px;
background:#c7dbe3;
background:rgba(199,219,227,0.90);
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
border-radius:5px;
border:1px solid #004f68;
box-shadow:3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
overflow:hidden
}
</style>
Ofcoure, my HTML:

<div id="vertel-me-meer"><p><a href="#" id="clickme" style="text-decoration: none;">Ik wil meer weten…</a></p></div>
<div id="weten">This Id your Box</div>
```

Comment: It will be better if you can state real cause and only specific code here instead of pasting the whole code as above.